# How to destroy all user sessions via WP-CLI

Tags: users, wp-cli, session

In installed WP-CLI v1.5.0

I ran `wp --info` and it return the correct info.

I then ran `wp user session destroy user1 --all` and got this:

`CORRECT>w user session destroy prvweb -all (y|n|e|a)?`

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I see no reference to this in the docs, have you opened a ticket on the WP CLI issue tracker?

Comment: hmmm there **is** one afterall, you didn't mention there's a discussion going on at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-destroy-all-user-sessions-via-wp-cli/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using `zsh` and `CORRECT`, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html.

You should be able to use `unsetopt correct` to disable that completely or `nocorrect wp ...` to disable it for just that command.